# Making a loss when working a delivery job?

Tags: salary, united-kingdom, employer

I occasionally do part time delivery work for a local takeaway. They provide an amount of pay for 3 hours. However if I do a large range of deliveries in large quantities, I often find after counting my money I don't make any money but in fact a loss from the cost of petrol outweighing the pay. The employer keeps tips and delivery charges.

My question is, is there any way I can negotiate getting the delivery charges, or would it be legal for me to keep the tips and not make the employer aware. Or even just quit as it's obviously it's not worth it as I'm not actually getting the amount of pay I'm being told.

Comment: How do you make a loss, i.e. what are your expenses? For fuel?

Comment: Are you driving a car to deliver? There's a reason most takeaway couriering is done by motorcycle/scooter.

Comment: @Carcer May be area dependant but there’s nobody out here riding to deliveries

Comment: *"The employer keeps tips"* Do you mean ones paid on credit-card, or cash tips you receive at the door (you always keep these, right?? a) In some areas employer keeping tips is illegal (look into this) b) Hint to your customers to tip cash, esp. if they ask how to tip you.

Comment: Are you in a labour union?

Comment: FWIW (though I'm obviously biased as I answered) I don't think the close reason is correct: failure to pay expenses/minimum wage/tips isn't company-specific, and any relevant legal advice is "general knowledge" in the sense mentioned in [this meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1861/4828).

Comment: @Twyxz: no he didn't, and he was wildly speculating. Without knowing about your labor laws and contract (if you even have one), he *speculated* that it would be "fraudulent" if your contract were to say your employer got to keep CC tips. Ignore that sort of comment.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: Yes, the close reason is wrong. FWIW, I voted to close as "unclear", because the Q is simply confusing (the main issue being that it's unclear how OP is losing money).

Comment: @sleske I made an edit

Comment: @Twyxz: Yes, looks better. Voting to reopen (though you already have good answers anyway).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you are employed by the takeaway, then as you are in the UK, you are covered by minimum wage legislation. Your employer should be paying you the costs of doing the deliveries, plus the national minimum wage (which varies by age). If they're not, you should demand this - which may in practice result in you losing your job, but either way you'll be owed back pay for the difference.

There's a possibility you are actually "self-employed", in which you have no recourse other than to leave as you are considered to be responsible for yourself. However, it's very tempting for businesses to classify people as self-employed when they're not, and you can challenge that status - there have been some well-publicised court cases about this, for example [this one](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-44465639). You can read the definition of self-employed [here](https://www.gov.uk/employment-status/selfemployed-contractor). I think you could probably point to not getting to keep tips as one piece of evidence that you aren't self-employed. If you're paid hourly rather than by the delivery I think that would also strengthen your case.

If you are employed, have a look at 
https://checkyourpay.campaign.gov.uk/#is_your_employer_paying_you_properly_ for more information on your rights.

As mentioned on that page, you can also talk to [ACAS](https://www.gov.uk/pay-and-work-rights) or [report them directly to HMRC, anonymously](https://www.tax.service.gov.uk/forms/form/pay-and-work-rights-complaint/new#1).

They may also be obliged to hand over your tips in addition to the minimum wage, but I'm not sure of the exact rules on that. For example it might be ok for your employer to collect them and share with the "non customer facing" staff like the cooks. There's some information about it [here](https://www.gov.uk/tips-at-work) and it's another thing you can ask ACAS/HMRC about.

You have no direct rights to any delivery charge your employer charges customers, but of course they may use that to fund paying you your wages and expenses.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/tips-at-work

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thanks, added a note about that.

Comment: Just to make this a little more clear: **What your employer is doing is illegal. He does owe you the money.**

Comment: This answer assumes the OP is a worker or an employee under UK employment law. They may be a self-employed contractor (as for Deliveroo, Uber, Amazon, etc drivers) in which case they are not covered by minimum wage legislation. Before doing anything the OP needs to establish their status.

Comment: @stuart10 thanks, that's a very good point which considerably weakens my answer. I've added a paragraph to adress it now.

Answer (score 50):

What are delivery charges?

From what I remember working delivery we had 3 values - my rate (very low), fuel price and tips. At the end of the week I showed distance I travelled, my MpG and received money to cover this expense I made at the beginning of workweek.

So my employer paid for my time and resources. Tips were mine to keep (as in I didn't enclosed them when returning from delivery).

If your employer is keeping tips and not covering the cost of fuel I would advise to leave the job. It doesn't look like it is worth the hassle of negotiating.

But of course I would keep it simple, just say (don't ask) that you think you should be keeping delivery charges and tips as they are basically cost of delivery made by you.

If they won't agree with you - leave.

Comment: Delivery charges are like fuel price, it's what the customer pays to cover the cost of fuel

Comment: So yes, those should be paid to you. Owners can mace a little money off them (as sometimes DC will be 2 pounds but you only use fuel for 50p). and if they are flexible (above certain order value delivery is free) you should know when customer pay them.

Comment: @Twyxz so you're not getting the delivery charge that the customer has paid, yet you are covering the cost of fuel?  Is it intended to be covered by your base rate?

Comment: @Twyxz I am pretty sure it ***should*** cover insurance and vehicle maintenance too.

Comment: Well the takeaway is quite busy so the rate the pay me is above minimum wage (not by much) so at the end of a night I tend to burn into this base rate through petrol charges. So my earnings are less or are even non-existent

Comment: I feel at the end of the night I should at least come out with £25 pound after all the petrol has been put in etc,,,

Comment: So yeah, in short: Tips should be yours to keep, delivery charges should cover your petrol cost. I think you can do better with uber eats.

Comment: Please don’t put multiple spaces at the end of lines or sentences, it breaks the Markdown formatting — the result is that your paragraphs are now broken across lines rather than being formatted as consistent paragraphs (I would simply fix this but I can’t make edits consisting only of whitespace changes).

Comment: @Twyxz in the UK expenses necessary to perform your job must be covered in addition to you being paid the minimum wage (see Ganesh's answer), so your employer is currently NOT paying you minimum wage, and is breaking the law.

Answer (score 15):

> is there any way I can negotiate getting the delivery charges

You can try, but I strongly suspect you'll get the answer "no". Your employer is pretty clearly abusive.

> or would it be legal for me to keep the tips and don't make the employer aware

No. If your contract says that they keep the tips, they keep the tips. Hiding tips from them is pretty clearly fraudulent.

> Or even just quit

This is always an option. While in general we say "don't quit without a new job to go to", if you're actually *losing* money doing this, just quit right now.

Comment: “Your employer is pretty clearly abusive.“ never blame to malice what can be explained with ignorance.

Comment: Philip is the part about the tips correct regarding the UK legislation?

Comment: @Mindwin IANAL. [Turns out to be non-trivial and depends on whether they are cash tips given directly to an employee or cheque/card/electronic payments](https://www.bighospitality.co.uk/Article/2015/08/27/What-are-legal-tip-policies).

Comment: Just saying: I’m giving tips to drivers. I’m absolutely NOT giving tips to the business. If I find out that the business takes the tips from you that I paid you, I’ll make them pay them back to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your employer may be breaking the law by withholding tips and/or failing to cover your expenses and a minimum wage, as others have noted above. Don't muddy the waters by potentially breaking the law yourself by keeping money under the table if there is a work agreement or contract that requires you to pass the tips along.

You should do two things: immediately start looking for another job. When you feel comfortable doing so, go to your employer and tactfully describe how you are losing money, and show it on paper with numbers. From the sound of things, they probably won't want to help you out, hence suggestion to look for another job.

I'm not sure that quitting immediately is beneficial, as a job that covers your living expenses minus 50 lbs a month (just hypothetically) is better than no job and being in the hole for all of your living expenses. The former (your present situation) is admittedly not sustainable in the long term, but the latter is worse, it's a bit of a disaster if you can't immediately get another job.

Comment: This is only a part time job and I do have a full time job as well. However good suggestions, noted.

Comment: Glad to hear it. My only other advice is to avoid burning bridges, even if the other party deserves it. Good luck!

Comment: Someone wiser than me said: Never burn bridges. Some bridges need blowing up. Blow them up, don’t burn them.

Comment: I'm trying to think of circumstances where I would blow up a bridge. If I was aware that my boss was a child molester, it would be my duty to notify the police. In most other situations, being known as someone with good people skills is more useful to me than pyrotechnics. Others may disagree - I believe Donald Trump is famous for his use of revenge as a tool of business strategy. Not my style, though, and I haven't seen anything in OP's situation that suggests a scorched earth response.